# Robust standard errors fixed effects and first differencing

Tags: econometrics, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

Suppose that we have an unobserved effects model:
$y_{it}=\beta_0+\beta_1 x_{it}+a_i+u_{it}$ for $t=1,2$.

When we have two time periods for panel data, I read that fixed effects estimation and first differencing yield the same estimates for the parameters of the model as well as the same standard errors. I recently confirmed this in Stata.

When I used the robust standard errors, the estimates were still the same as expected, but the robust standard errors were different. The only explanation I can think of is that after first differencing the error term is $\Delta u_i$ whereas after the fixed effects transformation the error is $u_{it}-\bar{u}_i$ for $t=1,2$, so in the former case we only have to correct for heteroskedasticity whereas in the latter case we also have to worry about serial correlation in the errors.

Is this explanation correct? If so, would making both standard errors robust to heteroskedasticity alone result in the same standard errors?

Comment: My wild guess is: degrees of freedom. By first differencing the number of observations used in the estimation are reduced while for fixed effects the number of observations are not reduced. This should result in different degrees of freedom.